# Only picks the last database inserted result

Tags: php, mysql, database, replace, str-replace

I got this simple thing , it basically works , but there's something about it that does not sound right so, I got this:

```
$text = $_GET['text'];
$sitechoose=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site");
while($change=mysql_fetch_array($sitechoose)) {
    $o = $change['original'];
    $r = $change['changed'];
    $messages = str_replace($o, $r, $text);
}
echo messages;
```

So the replace thing works , but only replaces the $o and $r of the last databse result , any ideas why ? thanks!

EDIT:
$text supposed to be smiles / badwords etc...
while in mysql table original would be the smile :) amd changed would be

Comment: Is `$messages` supposed to be an array?

Comment: $messages [] = str_replace($o, $r, $text);

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be $text , but yes it is !

Comment: or if it is string use .=

Comment: That makes everything in the text go to "array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your `$messages` variable is a simple string. You need to make `$messages` an array. Your code should look like this instead:

```
$text = $_GET['text'];
$sitechoose = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site");
$messages = array();
while ($change = mysql_fetch_array($sitechoose)) {
    $o = $change['original'];
    $r = $change['changed'];
    $messages[] = str_replace($o, $r, $text);
}
echo $messages;
```

Assigning to `$messages[]` will push a new element onto the end of the array.

Comment: well errors saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @GotToFigure I'm guessing you're using an old version of PHP. I've updated to work with pre-5.4.x.

Comment: True I do indeed use an old version :! So I guess Im close to a solution but why its picking the last database inserted result dunno , Its what Im trying to figure , btw read the question EDIT might help :) thanks !

Comment: @GotToFigure Try `var_dump($messages)` instead to see the array contents.